# Gulp callback - How to tell Gulp to run a task first before another?

Tags: javascript, css, asynchronous, less, gulp

How can I tell Gulp to run a task first before another?

For instance, I need to crunch .less file into a .css first,

```
// Crunch less into css.
gulp.task('less', function () {

    return gulp.src([
        'css/myless.less'
    ])
    .pipe(less().on('error', function (err) {
        console.log(err);
    }))
    .pipe(cssmin().on('error', function(err) {
        console.log(err);
    }))
    .pipe(rename({suffix: '.less'}))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('css/'));

});
```

Then concat it with other normal .css files,

```
var concat = require('gulp-concat'),
    minifyCSS = require('gulp-minify-css'),
    clean = require('gulp-clean');

// CSS concat, auto-prefix and minify
gulp.task('styles', function() {
  gulp.src([
        'css/myless.less.css',
        'css/normal.css'
    ])
    .pipe(concat('main.css'))
    .pipe(minifyCSS())
    .pipe(gulp.dest('css/'));
});
```

Run task,

```
gulp.task('default', ['less', 'styles'], function() {

})
```

It only optimise 'css/normal.css', but not does not concat it with 'css/myless.less.css'.

What should I do?

Comment: FYI: if you don't add a `return` before your `gulp.src(` gulp doesn't know when your task has finished and will start the next task right away! (You're missing it in your "styles" task)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your `styles` task should depend on the `less` one to wait for its completion. Doing what you did will run the two tasks in parallel.

You can specify an array of dependent task on each task of your *gulpfile*:

```
gulp.task('styles', ['less'], function () {
```

Then your `default`task should look like this:

```
gulp.task('default', ['styles']);
```

Comment: Is a `return` statement also necessary, as Pylinux suggested?  I see that `styles` depends on `less`, and `less` has a `return`.  I'm wondering if that is necessary or frivolous.

Comment: @mareoraft the `return` tell gulp that your task run async, and that it will wait for completion. Since the `less` task is returning its stream, the `styles` one will correctly wait for it to finish, and since noone depend on the `styles` tasks, you can omit the return.